# How to append data to block from R/S?

Tags: red, red-system

I am trying to append data to `block` from Red/System.

```
Red []

my-red-block: ["some text"] ; some already existen data in block

foo: routine [
    blk
]
[
    block/rs-append as red-block! blk as red-value! unicode/load-utf8 "new text" size? "new text"
]

foo my-red-block

print my-red-block
```

I decided to pass `block` to `routine` end modify it there.

I am getting error:

```
*** Runtime Error 1: access violation
*** at: 630EB4DFh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for that is because [`load-utf8`](https://github.com/red/red/blob/7509ffd29769d1254dc8a9787d3972b5e4b34e85/runtime/unicode.reds#L640) returns a `node!` that references an external string buffer, not the `string!` value itself.

`node!` is essentially a pointer, and it doesn't match the structure of high-level Red values; however, since it's a pointer, it can be casted to a pointer of another type, like e.g. `red-value!` or any other struct. The crash happens when you try to access that malformed value slot.

As for the original question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62412324/5889272) should answer it.