# How to pass block with context to routine?

Tags: red, red-system

I am continue to learn Red/System. And now I am trying to understand how to pass word with context to function.

Here is my code:

```
Red [Note: "compile in release mode (-r flag)"]

mycontext: context [
    list: []
]

foo: routine [
    blk 
    /local        
    int [integer!]
    str [c-string!]
][
    blk: as red-block! _context/get-any <CONTEXTHERE> symbol/make "list" ; ?? <CONTEXTHERE>
    int: 123
    str: "Hello"

    block/rs-append blk as red-value! integer/box int
    string/load-in str length? str blk UTF-8
]

foo mycontext ; passing context to foo
probe mycontext
```

This code do not work because list is placed in `mycontext`. The example of passing `list` without context can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62410275/how-to-pass-value-from-red-system-to-red)

I tried different approaches, but every time I got error.

https://github.com/red/red/blob/master/runtime/datatypes/structures.reds#L188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the type specification of your routine is incorrect (that's what the error message tells you):

```
Compiling to native code...
*** Compilation Error: invalid definition for function exec/foo: [
    blk [red-red-block!]
    /local
    int [integer!]
    str [c-string!]
]
```

Compiler automatically puts `red-*` prefix for routine's arguments, so the correct specification should be:

```
foo: routine [
    blk [block!]
    /local        
        int [integer!]
        str [c-string!]
][
    ...
]
```

Secondly, this isn't correct either; you are passing an `object!`, not a `block!`:

```
*** Compilation Error: datatype not allowed
```

Which means that one should write:

```
foo: routine [
    obj [object!]
    /local        
        int [integer!]
        str [c-string!]
][
    ...
]
```

Now, as I understand, you want to get a hold of that empty block referenced by `list` and append values to it. This requires having a context node

```
obj/ctx
```

and symbol ID

```
symbol/make "list"
```

Having two in place we can make a call to `_context/get-any`:

```
foo: routine [
    obj [object!]
    /local
        blk [red-block!]
        int [integer!]
        str [c-string!]
][
    blk: as red-block! _context/get-any symbol/make "list" obj/ctx
    int: 123
    str: "Hello"

    block/rs-append blk as red-value! integer/box int
    string/load-in str length? str blk UTF-8
]
```

Alternative solution would be to construct a `word!` value using `word/load` and call `object/rs-select`:

```
foo: routine [
    obj [object!]
    /local
        blk [red-block!]
        int [integer!]
        str [c-string!]
][
    blk: as red-block! object/rs-select obj as red-value! word/load "list"
    int: 123
    str: "Hello"

    block/rs-append blk as red-value! integer/box int
    string/load-in str length? str blk UTF-8
]
```

Both approaches yield the expected result:

```
make object! [
    list: [123 "Hello"]
]
```

Personally, I wouldn't complicate things that much and simply pass the block to your routine:

```
mycontext: context [
    list: []
]

foo: routine [
    blk [block!]
    /local
        int [red-integer!]
        str [c-string!]
][
    str: "Hello"
    int: as red-integer! stack/push*
    int/header: TYPE_INTEGER
    int/value: 123

    block/rs-append blk as red-value! int
    string/load-in str length? str blk UTF-8
]

foo mycontext/list
probe mycontext
```

Comment: Could you show the simple way of passing block to routine? It should be someting like: `foo in mycontext 'list` ?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov `foo mycontext/list` should suffice; or `foo get in mycontext 'list` if you want to go that route.

Comment: I tried `b [block!]` and `blk: as red-block! _context/get-any symbol/make "list" b/ctx` but it's seems that block do not have context and I do not know how to pass it

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov if you already have a block `blk`, then all that you need to do is to append values to it.

Comment: please add full example to answer. I tried but get `Runtime Error 1: access violation` at it's run. It's seems that I did something wrong again.

Comment: Bit thanks! But why nothing do not work without `int: as red-integer! stack/push*` and `int/header: TYPE_INTEGER`?

Comment: @DmitryBubnenkov I extended my answer with an extra example; the crash is likely related to how `integer/box` handles data stack: it overwrites the bottom of the stack frame (with `blk` slot in it), which trips up `block/rs-append`. In my example I avoided that by boxing integer manually; alternative solution would be to duplicate `blk` on stack and let the bottom slot be reused.